# How to run IF JS logic based on a percentage chance?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable and I want the variable to affect the chance of a function being ran. For example:

```
var chance = 0.80;

function () {
 if(????) { <== I want this to only run 80% of the time, or whatever chance is set to
}
}
```

The function is going to run every few seconds. As chance gets higher I want the probability of the function running to increase.

Comment: `if (Math.random() < chance) { }`

Comment: Look up Math.random()

Answer (score 4):

Try this(I tried to leave your existing code alone):

```
...
if(Math.random() < chance){
//code goes here
}
```

The good thing about keeping the `chance` variable in place is it allows you to change the chance mid-execution.

Comment: Thanks. I know about Math.random, but I didn't even think of comparing it to my variable.